# How to relogin in apps when user deleted facebook apps in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to detect when user deleted facebook apps in Android and our application automatically clear access token and need relogin as new account? because the session is cached locally on the device after the user initially grants your app permissions, and i dont know how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage every app to make a request to something like /me or /me/permissions on startup, because the only way to know that your unexpired cached access token is no longer valid is to actually make a request. That way if the request fails, you'll know that the user needs to login again.